# jQuery - handling null/undefined responses

Tags: jquery, null, undefined

Where does this go wrong:

```
$('#prod').on('click', '.doc', function() {
 var src = this.value;
     if (! src) {
         var url = this.id;
          window.open('' + url + '');
  } else {
       var encodedSrc = encodeURIComponent(src);   
        $('#inner').html('<iframe id = dFrame src = http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodedSrc + '&embedded=true></iframe>');
```

The class .doc refers to several dynamically generated buttons in the div 'prod'.  They all have both an id and a value which are being used to pass links to the click function.  the value of the button refers to a document, the id to a URL.  No button has data in both the id and value - the aim is that sometimes clicking a button will open a new window at the URL specified in the button id; at other times it will open Google Reader in an iframe and display the document referenced in the button value.  The code above was meant to:

Get the value from the clicked button;
if it is null, get the id and open a new window at the URL in the id;
if it is not null, URIencode the button value and load Google reader.

I can get one or other to work, but not both.

Comment: how do you say you are not getting both to work? can you give some samples of the buttons you are testing against

Comment: With the code above, exactly as it is, the button id is retrieved as just 'id', so, in the case of button with an id but no value, the second part of the code still tries to execute and there is an error.  It seems I cannot get both the id and the value.  This is the code that creates the buttons (in an `append()` function): `<button class = doc value = ' + doc + ' id = ' + link + ' >Details</button>`

Comment: Can you get the html from the generated source?

Comment: we want to see the values associated with each attributes....

Comment: The 'value' of the button is a .doc or .pdf, the id is a conventional URL (ending in .com, etc.).

Comment: This isn't an answer but a solution.  I couldn't get both the 'value' and the 'id' from the button, so I put both types of content in the one variable ('value') and then regex-ed the value to decide what to do: `$('#prod').on('click', '.doc', function() {
  var src = this.value;
  if (src.match('com$')) {
     window.open('' + src + '');
  }  else  {
  var encodedSrc = encodeURIComponent(src);   
  $('#inner').html('').html('<iframe id = dFrame src = http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodedSrc + '&embedded=true></iframe>');`  Maybe not elegant, but it works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the original question, but a workaround that achieves the same result, if anyone is interested.

```
$('#prod').on('click', '.doc', function() { 
    var src = this.value; 
    if (src.match('com$')) { 
      window.open('' + src + ''); 
 } else { 
    var encodedSrc = encodeURIComponent(src); 
    $('#inner').html('<iframe id = dFrame src = http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodedSrc + '&embedded=true></iframe>');
```

If the button value is a file, it gets loaded in an iframe via Google viewer on button click; if it's a url, it gets loaded in a new window.